# Does OpenWhisk support OpenAPI 3.x specification?

Tags: openwhisk

Is it possible to import OpenAPI/Swagger 3.0 specification file to create APIs in OpenWhisk? I am able to import 2.0 specification file, but when I convert the file to 3.0, I hit the following error.

```
error: Unable to parse swagger file: Swagger file is invalid (missing basePath, info, paths, or swagger fields)
```

I am using open source OpenWhisk on self hosted Kubernetes cluster, not the one hosted on IBM Cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet but the project welcomes contributions. Some of the route management API and the OpenWhisk CLI will require adjustments to align the schema with OpenAPI.